# WindowsPhone 8.1 Visibility

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visibility

I'm writing a WP-8.1 application and i'm using Page class.
I would like to know when my Page loses visibility the reason, for instance, because the user pressed the "windows" button or due to outgoing call which my page initiated (the page uses webview that i can't control).
I'm using the Window.Current.VisibilityChanged API to receive the event of visibility change.
Does anyone know if it's possible?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the right event, but you might also want to look at the `Activated` event as well since that will tell you about incoming calls, reminders, and other things that partially obscure your app and take focus. It doesn't tell you about toast notifications though.

Comment: Hello, can you please elaborate or give an example how to use it?

Comment: The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.activated.aspx) have a minimal sample. Do you need anything more?